# How can I calculate percentage based on an over score

Tags: microsoft-excel

The spreadsheet that I have contains 30 questions where someone can score a 1 for a yes and a 0 for a no. I need that to calculate the percentage dependent on their overall score in a "total" field that should not exceed 100%.

Comment: Where is the problem exactly? `Score/30 = percentage`

Comment: I just don't know the formula I guess.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the percentage of different answers for each question, or the percentage of different answers for all 30 translations. Please provide more information of your needs. And you may try the [Countif function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34#:~:text=Use%20COUNTIF%2C%20one%20of%20the,want%20to%20look%20for%3F)) to get the count, or [Sumif function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) to get the score.

Comment: I need to calculate the overall percentage of different answers for all 30 translations. so for example if I were to manually calculate this I would do it as 30*100/30=100%

Comment: @Cynthia I made a sample with 10 statistics, and set cells as Percentage format to show value. For "Yes", the percentage uses formula "=COUNTIF(B1:B10,"1")/10", for "No", it uses "=COUNTIF(B1:B10,"0")/10". ([The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBIIv.jpg).)